# Can anybody identifies type of this socket on MSI GForce Super video-cards?

Tags: pcb, connector, identification, socket

I need to identify these two connectors on videocard's PCB to by them.
They are for backlight system and alike JST SH04 or Molex Picoblade, but i am not sure about it.

[image: MSI GForce 2060 Super's PCB]
[image: Other angle]

Comment: If you look at photos of the JST SH04 and Molex Picoblade male connectors and compare it to what you have then you may see differences that identify it one way or the other.

Comment: @AndrewMorton That's why i have asked for help - i can't find exact connector nor in JST nor in Molex datasheets.

Comment: Do you have a connector that goes into those sockets?

Comment: @AndrewMorton [Yes i have.](https://easycaptures.com/fs/uploaded/1207/0778912494.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like TE Part [1734260-4](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/te-connectivity-amp-connectors/1734260-4/A98738CT-ND/1855518) only different color. There are a couple similar options from TE so you would need to verify pitch.

[image]

Comment: TE 1734260 looks very close, but it is not .For example in TE pins have vertical orientation, in my connector - horizontal.I have looked at connectors carefully and found letters - they are very small. On the black it is "HJSY F1" and on the red "HJSY M3". may be it helps and i have measured distance between pins - it is 1.25mm.

Comment: Any chance you can get a better picture so I can see the pins on your connector.